# Художественное оформление текста

Tags: стилистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на ваш взгляд можно более художественно оформить следующий абзац (если он вообще нуждается в переработке)?

Исходный вариант:

Милое девчачье сокровище: брошка, пожелтевший кружевной платочек с вышивкой, несколько пуговиц, засохшая палочка, видимо, когда-то бывшая стебельком цветка, лепестки, совсем рассыпались, почти превратившись в пыль. А вот фотографии, маленькие, и не различишь, кто на них изображён.

И два моих варианта (может быть можно как-то скомбинировать):

Милое девчачье сокровище: брошка, пожелтевший кружевной платочек с вышивкой, несколько пуговиц, засохшая палочка, видимо, когда-то бывшая стебельком цветка, лепестки — совсем рассыпались, почти превратившись в пыль. А вот фотографии: маленькие, и не различишь, кто на них изображён.

Милое девчачье сокровище: брошка, пожелтевший кружевной платочек с вышивкой, несколько пуговиц, засохшая палочка, видимо, когда-то бывшая стебельком цветка, лепестки… совсем рассыпались, почти превратившись в пыль. А вот фотографии — маленькие, и не различишь, кто на них изображён.

Answer (score 3):

Смотря сколько позволительно изменить в тексте. Он в принципе смотрится плохо с этим избыточным перечислением. Его следовало бы разбить на два по-разному переработанных отрывка, но судя по всему, вы полагаете необходим исключительно заменить знаки препинания. На мой взгляд, самым лучшим вариантом будет следующий:

Милое девчачье сокровище: брошка, пожелтевший кружевной платочек с вышивкой, несколько пуговиц, засохшая палочка, видимо, когда-то бывшая стебельком цветка, лепестки — совсем рассыпались, почти превратившись в пыль. А вот фотографии — маленькие, и не различишь, кто на них изображён.